# How can i enumerate through tkinter label and highlight or underline each word

Tags: python, tkinter, label, underline

I am looking for a way to underline each word in a label text per condition I've set.

I looked for similar questions posed before and I've only managed to either Underline the entire text at once or one single letter. My app is essentially supposed to be a text typing application. For now i'm tracking each word, I would like to Underlining the upcoming word. here's my code.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import font

    class App:
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.count = 0
            l = Label(text="Hello, world")
            l.pack()
            f = font.Font(l,l.cget("font"))
            f.configure(underline = True)
            l.configure(font=f)
            self.root.mainloop()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app=App()
```

For example purposes one can use the `self.root.after(mili, method)`

I'm using tkinter python 3.6.6
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to use a `Text` widget instead. There's no way to have different fonts in a single Label.

Comment: I've done it with both the Text and Message widget, but as soon as i turn them to "disabled", which is what i would need so that i cannot easily copy the text, it thus becomes difficult or improbable to retrieve the text to manipulate it's font or tag.  I just thought because there is a way to highlight 1 letter in a label and a way to highlight the whole thing. Then surely there would be a way to maybe loop through each letter or word somehow. :thinking:

Answer (score 1):

You can't highlight individual words in a `Label` widget. If you need that capability, you will need to use a `Text` widget.